# Animating the position of a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, animation, jframe

I have made a simple `JFrame` (320 X 64) That I am displaying (undecorated(true);) in the top of the screen.  Is there a simple way to draw the `JFrame` above the screen, slide it down, wait a couple seconds, and go back up and dispose?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use `Swing Timer` and `JFrame#setLocation(int x,int y)`

Here is a small example I made:

It simply starts a `Swing Timer` to move *undecorated* `JFrame` from starting co-ordinates in downward direction (on y-axis) until it reaches the bottom of the screen which is got via `GraphicsEnvironment#getMaximumWindowBounds()`. It than starts a new `Swing Timer` 2500 milliseconds afterwards to move `JFrame` back up to the top of the screen and than `dispose()` `JFrame` when done:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class AnimateJFrame {

    private JFrame frame;

    public AnimateJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        frame = new JFrame() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(300, 300);
            }
        };
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        createAndStartDownwardTimer(frame);
    }

    private void createAndStartDownwardTimer(final JFrame frame) {
        new Timer(25, new AbstractAction() {
            int screenHeight = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds().height;
            int y = frame.getY();

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if (frame.getY() + frame.getHeight() < screenHeight) {
                    y += 10;
                    frame.setLocation(frame.getX(), y);
                } else {
                    createAndStartUpwardTimer(2500 - 15);//15milis approx latency
                    ((Timer) ae.getSource()).stop();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void createAndStartUpwardTimer(int initialDelay) {
        Timer t = new Timer(25, new AbstractAction() {
            int y = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds().height - frame.getHeight();

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if (frame.getY() > 0) {
                    y -= 10;
                    frame.setLocation(frame.getX(), y);
                } else {
                    frame.dispose();
                    ((Timer) ae.getSource()).stop();
                }
            }
        });
        t.setInitialDelay(initialDelay);
        t.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new AnimateJFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```